# Java Array Not Updating Elements

Tags: java, arrays, char

When this code runs, the char variables contained in the array do not update and remain a blank space. The TicTacToe board prints in the correct format. Am I missing something obvious?

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pos;
        boolean win = false;

        
        char tl = ' '; char tm = ' '; char tr = ' ';
        char ml = ' '; char mm = ' '; char mr = ' ';
        char bl = ' '; char bm = ' '; char br = ' ';
        
        // INITIALIZE ARRAY
        char[] tic = new char[15];
        tic[0] = tl; tic[1] = '|'; tic[2] = tm; tic[3] = '|'; tic[4] = tr;
        tic[5] = ml; tic[6] = '|'; tic[7] = mm; tic[8] = '|'; tic[9] = mr;
        tic[10] = bl; tic[11] = '|'; tic[12] = bm; tic[13] = '|'; tic[14] = br;
        
        
            System.out.println("Player 1: Make your move!");
            System.out.println("Choose between: TL TM TR ML MM MR BL BM BR");
        
            pos = scan.next();
        
            if(pos == "TL") {tl = 'X'; }
            if(pos == "TM") {tm = 'X'; }
            if(pos == "TR") {tr = 'X'; }
            if(pos == "ML") {ml = 'X'; }
            if(pos == "MM") {mm = 'X'; }
            if(pos == "MR") {mr = 'X'; }
            if(pos == "BL") {bl = 'X'; }
            if(pos == "BM") {bm = 'X'; }
            if(pos == "BR") {br = 'X'; }
            
            System.out.println("Player 2: Make your move!");
            System.out.println("Choose between: TL TM TR ML MM MR BL BM BR");
            
            pos = scan.next();
            
            if(pos == "TL") {tl = 'O'; }
            if(pos == "TM") {tm = 'O'; }
            if(pos == "TR") {tr = 'O'; }
            if(pos == "ML") {ml = 'O'; }
            if(pos == "MM") {mm = 'O'; }
            if(pos == "MR") {mr = 'O'; }
            if(pos == "BL") {bl = 'O'; }
            if(pos == "BM") {bm = 'O'; }
            if(pos == "BR") {br = 'O'; }
            
            // PRINT BOARD
            for(int i = 0; i <= 14; i++)
            {
                    System.out.print(tic[i]);
                    
                    if(i == 4 || i == 9) 
                    {
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                
                    
            }
```

I was messing around and realized that I have no idea how to resolve this issue

Comment: use `pos.equals("TL")` instead of `pos == "TL"`

Comment: *Am I missing something obvious?*  - Yes.  Don't compare strings using `==`.  It (typically) doesn't work.  See dup link.

Comment: You have to use the equals method.